# encryption in php

Tags: php, encryption

```
$key = file_get_contents('http://keyserver.pramberger.at/pks/lookup?op=get&search=userid');
```

this code gives me public key with the html tag .how to extract the public key block form begin pgp public key block ---to---- end pgp public key block  and using this public key i need to encrypt the data .i need to do it in php.

Comment: Your questions are all very similar. Why don't you state your question clearly and also provide code examples what you have done so far. Also creating a second account is not for you advantage I guess.

Answer (score 2):

try this
`preg_match('/PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----\s(.*?)\s-----END PGP/s', $data, $match);

echo $match[1]; //returns the key`

Answer (score 0):

or that

```
$pgp_key = trim(preg_replace('/(.*)<pre>(.*)<\/pre>(.*)/s','\2',$key));
```